# NGRX 5 piped selector

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

In [this](https://medium.com/ngrx/ngrx-5-and-schematics-2d8cc3906506) article on medium.com (13 Feb.) regarding NGRX 5 they present pipeable selectors. This reminds me on reading about pipeable selectors in rxjs where they could not just be justified by 'its pure function, bro', but also by the way functions could be declared and reused in different occurences without using map every time to then call a letable function.

So i can agree, that this is a good thing in rxjs, but why would we need this in ngrx - for selectors. The linked article shows the following example:

```
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

interface AppState {
  count: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
    <div>Current Count: {{ count$ | async }}</div>
    <button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>

    <button (click)="reset()">Reset Counter</button>
  `
})
export class MyAppComponent {
  count$: Observable<number>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.count$ = store.pipe(select('count'));
  }
}
```

So we now call `store.pipe(select(...));`
instead of `store.select(Selector);` - where are the gains? why should i change my code to use this behaviour or at least start to use pipeable selectors?

Comment: Because it's best practice to use the same selector style throughout the application, and the old way may become deprecated after rxjs6 gains wide adoption. I you have issues with changing code frequently, angular is going to drive you insane.

Comment: because you'll probably use it everywhere where you use rxjs in general so having it in ngrx store related things make sense for the same benefits: smaller footprint and code unification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NgRx 7 this deprecation is been reverted - [see changelog](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#700-beta0-2018-11-03).